# How to find the complex roots of $2^z = z^2$?

Tags: lambert-w

Plotting the function on the real axis reveals that it has three solutions

[image]

Therefore the solution set is:

$$
z = \left\{-\frac{2}{\ln2}W\left(\frac{\ln2}{2}\right),2,4\right\}
$$

---

But plotting in the complex plane reveals that there are other solutions far away from the real axis.

[image]

The numerical approximation result is:

$$
z≈7.65±11.95i
$$

How should we give the expression for the complex solution of the original equation?

Comment: wolfram gives answer using W functkion. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+2%5Ez+%3D+z%5E2

Comment: To see the pattern of roots, I recommend plotting the equations Re(2^z - z^2) = 0 and Im(2^z - z^2) = 0. The complex roots will be those points common to both loci. (Where 2^z denotes exp(ln(2)*z).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lambert $W$ function is multivalued, with infinitely many branches.  The one you're taking as $W(\ln(2)/2)$ is the "$0$" branch.  The complex roots correspond to the other branches.  Branches $1$ to $5$ correspond to complex roots approximately

$$   7.654506496- 11.95367891 \,\mathrm{i}, 
 10.03684857- 30.81806330 \,\mathrm{i}, 
 11.31574563- 49.20372800 \,\mathrm{i}, 
 12.19872547- 67.46928744 \,\mathrm{i}, 
 12.87413263- 85.68453064 \,\mathrm{i} $$

and $-1$ to $-5$ the complex conjugates of those.

Comment: I want to know what the series forms of other branches are? I didn't find it on wiki([Asymptotic expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)), so I didn't calculate their high-precision numerical solutions.

Comment: Some expressions are on [Wolfram functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/)

Comment: You can use Newton's method to find high precision  numerical solutions near low precision solutions.